# While creating a workflow variable(of type String) for a hyperlink field in SPDesigner 2013, the return field is "As Dictionary from JSON"

Tags: hyperlink, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, url-parameters, sharepoint-workflow

Scenario : 
I have a list of items. This list has columns with text value information(**lets say Val1, Val2, Val**3,..) and links which will take the user to the other pages. One of these fields is a **URL column (type - hyperlink**) which acts as a filter. On clicking the URL, it directs to another page and filters the page for each specific value(*for e.g Val1*) from the parent page.

So to achieve this,

```
- I created a new workflow in SP Designer 2013, 
- Created a workflow variable of type String (lets say **'WFVar1'**) and added to Action ‘Set Workflow Variable’
- For the ‘value’ in the action I clicked the 3 dots (…) on the right, I set the URL for e.g
https://abc.xyx.com/thisisanexample.aspx and then clicked on Add or
Change Lookup and set the field from Source as Val1. The return
field automatically fills up *"As String"*. The URL is now followed
by Val1.
- Once done with the URL and description, I added the workflow Action ‘Set Field in Current Item'
- I clicked ‘field’ in the Action and choose the hyperlink field(URL) of the list.
```

Here comes the issue :

- I click the ‘value’ in the Action and choose ‘workflow Variable and
  Parameters’ and select the variable  WFVar1. The return field
  automatically gets set to ***"As Dictionary from JSON"*** instead of
  "As String".

Due to the type difference, the workflow doesn't work and remains suspended.

Need help!!

Answer (score 0):

URL fields do contain multiple string values for the URL and text description.

Since the return type is a dictionary, you may need to store it into a dictionary variable and then extract out the text and URL into separate string variable for later use.

If you need to know what the fields in the JSON are, you can save the dictionary to a string variable and write it out to the log if the JSON string is less than 250 characters, else it will also lock up and in that case you can write the value to a multi-line text field in a list which has a length limit of 64k characters.